# Combined flair does not show

Tags: bug, flair

I've just checked my profile page, where I put my combined flair to show my activity among the other stackexchange sites, but it isn't working anymore. Even when I go to the page where I can select flairs, it has image broken link.

Can you guys check?

[this is my profile's link, where the flag should appear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2405914/leonardo-alves-machado?tab=profile)

This is the code that does not work:

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/2796827"><img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2796827.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Leonardo Alves Machado on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Leonardo Alves Machado on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites"></a>
```

And below is the flair selection page, where you can also check the broken flair
[image: Broken link]

Comment: Also on MSE: [Combined profiles flair image is not found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368165)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVdWd.png). What isn't working on it?

Comment: Mine works. Interesting. The direct access to your flair image works, too.

Comment: Luuklag suggested on the MSE post that it might be a location-specific CDN issue, which could explain why it works for many/ most but not for some.

Comment: by the way, still not solved. Checked right now

Comment: Was this forgotten?

Comment: Mine is also broken and I have it displayed in the footer of my website

Comment: Though I use Nord VPN and when I disconnected, it showed up again. I agree on the location-specific CDN issue.

Comment: To me, it [started working again a few weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368165/combined-profiles-flair-image-is-not-found#comment1233484_368165) - with or without VPN. I think they might have fixed it - I just wonder if it was fixed for everyone...

Comment: Also mine started to work. The MSE post is still in "status-review".

Comment: oh, man, problem is back :(